# Некорректное отображение метода Date. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
td = new Date('2017-05-16 13:45');
var dt = {
    time: td,
    value: '',
    add: function(val, type){

        this.value = this.time.toJSON();
        return this;
    }
};
dt.add();
console.log(dt.value);
```

Вывод такой:

```
2017-05-16T08:45:00.000Z
```

Почему некорректное время отображает? делает минус 5 часов (я нахожусь в зоне +5);
помогите!!!

Answer (score 0):

`toJSON()` пользуется функцией `toISOString()`, а этот метод, если нет указания на зону возвращает ответ с нулевой зоной:

```js
td = new Date('2017-05-16 13:45');
td2 = new Date('2017-05-16 13:45 UTC');

console.log(td.toJSON())
console.log(td2.toJSON())
console.log(td.toISOString())
console.log(td2.toISOString())
```